# inotifywait runs too often

Tags: linux, bash, inotify

I'm having some trouble with a Linux bash script to keep track on file changes on a directory.

I stumbled across inotify (in this case inotifywait), which is a very nice tool and runs my code as it should.

But it runs too often, can some one tell me how to stop this code from running over and over on the same files?

Just to clarify, the dir the script is running on is my photo rename folder, all photos/movies that are dropped here get renamed based on the exif information and then moved to the photo folder.

All of the internal code is removed to keep the discussion on the inotifywait command.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/data/RenamePhoto
NEWPATH=/mnt/photo

cd $PATH
# inotify will watch over the folder
/usr/bin/inotifywait --monitor \
     --recursive \
     --event close_write \
     --format %f ./ | while read FILE; do 
         /bin/sleep 5
         .....more code here......
done
```

Here is some output from inotifywait:

> ```
> Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
> Watches established.
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> File not found: IMG_3482.JPG
> /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘IMG_3482.JPG’: No such file or directory
> ```

As you can see it keeps on going over the same file, this behaviour is caused because the file is being changed while being written over the network.

I have added the 'sleep 5' to give the file write command some time to finish, but inotifywiat has a buffer as you can see.

Is there a away to just run this rename and mv command once per file?

Comment: Can you paste the output of this line: `/usr/bin/inotifywait -m -e close_write . | while read PATH ACTION FILE; do /usr/bin/echo $FILE ;done` ? Does the `echo` command get executed multiple times? I suspect the error in the omitted code rather than the `inotifywait` behavior.

Comment: This represents 1 write command of a file paste in the folder: /usr/bin/inotifywait -m -e close_write . | while read PATH ACTION FILE; do /bin/echo $FILE ;done
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG
iPhone4_IMG_3525.JPG

Comment: If you just `mv` a file to that folder it should work fine, just tried it on my machine. Maybe the program writing the picture does some unusual stuff like writing the file twice or internally saving multiple times.